# Is there a way to send data to a Kafka topic directly from within Processor?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to implement the following logic with help of Kafka Streams:

1. Listen to some reference data from topic eg. `ref-data-topic` and creates a global `StateStore` from it.
2. Listen to messages from another topic `data-topic` which must be validated against ref data and **either sent to `success` or `errors` topics**.

Here is example pseudocode:

```java
class SomeProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {

    private KeyValueStore<String, String> refDataStore;

    @Override
    public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
        refDataStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore("ref-data-store");
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key String value) {
        Object refData = refDataStore.get("some_key");

        // business logic here

        if(ok) {
           sendValueToTopic("success");
        } else {
           sendValueToTopic("errors");
        }
    }
}
```

Or what would be the canonical way to achieve such a desired behavior?

Just like an alternative that I have now in my mind is to enrich data within Processor with validation info and send everything then into only one topic, making a client to deal with e.g. `validationStatus` in the received message.

Although, I really would like to have a solution with two topics because e.g in such a case I could, using Kafka Connect, link `success topic` directly with some datastore and deal with `error topic` somehow differently. In the approach with only one topic, again, I have no idea how to achieve this "store_only_successfully_validated_entities" use case.

Any ideas and suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Processor API, you can forward data to different processor by name:

```java
class SomeProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {

    private KeyValueStore<String, String> refDataStore;
    private ProcessorContext processorContext;

    @Override
    public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
        refDataStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore("ref-data-store");
        processorContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String key String value) {
        Object refData = refDataStore.get("some_key");

        // business logic here

        if(ok) {
           processorContext.forward(key, value, To.child("success"));
        } else {
           processorContext.forward(key, value, To.child("error"));
        }
    }
}
```

When you plug in your topology, you add two sink nodes, names `"success"` and `"error"` that write to success and error topic respectively.

Or you `forward` data to a single sink node and add the sink with a `TopicNameExtractor` instead of a hard coded topic name. (Requires version 2.0.)

If you use DSL, you can use `KStream#branch()` to split a stream and pile different data to different topics via `KStream#to(...)` (or you use the dynamic routing via `KStream#to(TopicNameExtractor)` -- required version 2.0)